# Why is a single process pool faster than serialized implementation in this python code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm experiencing with multiprocessing in python. I know that it can be slower than serialized computation, this is not the point of my post.

I'm just wandering why a single process pool is faster than the serialized computation of my basic problem. Shouldn't these times be the same?

Here is the code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def func(x):
    return x*x*x


def multi_proc(nb_procs):
    tic = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=nb_procs)
    pool.map_async(func, range(1, 10000000))
    toc = time.time()
    return toc-tic


def single_core():
    tic = time.time()
    [func(x) for x in range(1, 10000000)]
    toc = time.time()
    return toc-tic

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc_times = [0]
    mc_times = [0]
    print('single core computation')
    sc_constant_time = single_core()
    print('{} secs'.format(sc_constant_time))
    for nb_procs in range(1, 12):
        print('computing for {} processes...'.format(nb_procs))
        time_elapsed = (multi_proc(nb_procs))
        print('{} secs'.format(time_elapsed))
        mc_times.append(time_elapsed)
    sc_times = [sc_constant_time for _ in mc_times]
    plt.plot(sc_times, 'r--')
    plt.plot(mc_times, 'b--')
    plt.xlabel('nb procs')
    plt.ylabel('time (s)')
    plt.show()
```

And the plot of times per number of processes (red = serial computation, blue = multiprocessing):
[image]

**EDIT 1:**
I modified my code as Sidhnarth Gupta indicated, and here is the new code I have. I changed my func for no reason.

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


def func(x):
    return random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])


def multi_proc(nb_procs, nb_iter):
    tic = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=nb_procs)
    pool.map_async(func, range(1, nb_iter)).get()
    toc = time.time()
    return toc-tic


def single_core(nb_iter):
    tic = time.time()
    [func(x) for x in range(1, nb_iter)]
    toc = time.time()
    return toc-tic

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # configure
    nb_iter = 100000
    max_procs = 16
    sc_times = [0]
    mc_times = [0]

    # multi proc calls
    for nb_procs in range(1, max_procs):
        print('computing for {} processes...'.format(nb_procs))
        time_elapsed = (multi_proc(nb_procs, nb_iter))
        print('{} secs'.format(time_elapsed))
        mc_times.append(time_elapsed)

    # single proc call
    print('single core computation')
    for nb in range(1, len(mc_times)):
        print('{}...'.format(nb))
        sc_times.append(single_core(nb_iter))
    # average time
    average_time = sum(sc_times)/len(sc_times)
    print('average time on single core: {} secs'.format(average_time))

    # plot
    plt.plot(sc_times, 'r--')
    plt.plot(mc_times, 'b--')
    plt.xlabel('nb procs')
    plt.ylabel('time (s)')
    plt.show()
```

Here is the new plot I have:

[image]

I think I can now say that I have increased my program's speed by using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code to calculate the time taken by multiprocessing is actually telling the time taken by the process to submit the task to the pool. The processing is actually happening in asynchronous mode without blocking the thread.

I tried your program with following changes:

```
def multi_proc(nb_procs):
    tic = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=nb_procs)
    pool.map_async(func, range(1, 10000000)).get()
    toc = time.time()
    return toc-tic
```

and

```
def multi_proc(nb_procs):
    tic = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=nb_procs)
    pool.map(func, range(1, 10000000))
    toc = time.time()
    return toc-tic
```

Both of them take significantly more time than then serialised computation.

Also while creating such graphs, you should also consider calling the single_core() function everytime you want to map the value instead of mapping the same value multiple time. You will see a significant variance in time taken by the same.

Comment: Great help. I added the modifications in my post. Could you confirm me I have achieved my goal of speeding up my program thanks to multiprocessing? I will accept your answer in that case :)

Comment: Yes, thats primarily the increase in performance you get. Also the blue line will come down depending on the number of cores your system have.